# How to disable letters in keyboard (leave only digits)?

Tags: android

I'm developing Android application, and I need to disable letters for user's keyboard in order to allow user to input only digits in EditText. Please, tell me, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:inputType="number"` to the EditText in the layout xml.

More information on inputType's can be found at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

You can also go further and do something like:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789"
/>
```

Comment: I've just made it, but it doesn't help. I want to HIDE letters keyboard.

Comment: what exactly do you want this to look like?  adding this attribute to the edittext would show a keyboard with only numbers.

Comment: If the keyboard is well implemented, it will make it pop up a number pad.  However it won't stop a keyboard from displaying letters if the user shifts layers on the keyboard-  nothing will do that, its at the IME's discression

Answer (score 0):

EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

OR

Using XML

android:inputType="number"